# How much air pressure are you supposed to apply to a sleeping mat?

Tags: sleeping-pads

I've purchased [this air mattress](https://www.rei.com/product/172611/sea-to-summit-comfort-light-insulated-air-sleeping-pad) and inflated it to the best of my abilities with my mouth. But it was still a bit soft and you could touch the ground if you put too much pressure on one section (it was fine when sleeping on it with body fully stretched out). Is this normal or do I need to use a hand pump to put in more pressure into it so that its fully firm?

Comment: Link says that there is a pump in the stuff sack included. Seems like you need to pump a bit.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks. Its not actual pump, more like a sack that you put air in and then apply pressure. I was able to add more air with my mouth than using that "pump".

Comment: Not an expert -- we only briefly had air mattresses -- but as long as it is OK when you are stretched out, I think it is OK.  Is it fine when you are curled up, or is that when a portion becomes soft?  If so, PIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the [ultralight version](https://www.seatosummit.co.uk/products/sleeping-mats/ultralight-mat/) of the same mat.  Mine is a little thinner: 5cm thick when inflated, compared to 6.3cm but they're very similar, and I can (just about) sleep on my side on mine, out straight.  I don't curl up.  It does need to be pumped up fairly firm, and if I sit on it I definitely reach the ground; positioning joints carefully when trying to get to sleep might be needed.  It's particularly important with a thin mat like these to check the ground for hard lumps, not just ones that can cause punctures (I use a thin tarp underneath for a little protection).

Using the inflation sack properly takes practise but can get more air pressure  in than blowing it up by mouth.  Don't blow it up like a balloon, but instead blow into the wide open end from some distance away.  The idea is to fill the bag with unpressurised air - your breath sweeps lots of air into the bag.  Then roll the top down and keep rolling or push to generate the pressure.  It only takes a few bagfuls this way, and this also puts less moisture inside than many lungfuls.  The S2S video for [your mat (I think)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wIm3YsUKIA) demonstrates reasonably well, with a bigger bag than mine has.

With a thin mat like this, I reckon if you managed to pump it up hard enough to support most of your weight on a small area, it would be so hard as to be uncomfortable for sleeping on.  That's true to some extent even with the old, heavy, thick rubberised cotton inflatable mats.